# How do I perform a mass update in MySQL with maximum performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to do a mass-update on a SQL database. Basically the scenario I have is this:

I have a field called *priority*. During certain transactions, I have to update this field for all records, approximately 2 million in number. Is there a MySQL statement to perform all updates in bulk and gives maximum performance ?

Ex: Something like this:

```
update my_model set priority = p1,p2,p3,p4.. where id = id1,id2,id3,id4..
```

I am using Ruby on Rails for this, so I am looking at raw SQL queries.

Also, on a side note, what is the most efficient way to do a bulk update in Rails (other than using transactions and update_all)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly better choice is you choose Stored Procedure. I had this type of situation long back, and we were dealing with prepared statements sort of things in java. we were fighting all sort of `-xm` things, but even after increasing 4 gb memory, we were failing to achieve faster. We decided to transport all database related code that handles millions of records at a time, to stored procedures, ( In my case, it was `oracle pl/sql` ), fastness improved by about 400% - 800%. (Reduced from 4 hours to half an hour).

Answer (score 1):

You can define [transaction block](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods)

In your case, it looks like you want to set `priority` same as ID :

```
MyModel.each
[1,2,3,4,5].each do |id|
  `MyModel.find(id).update_attribute(priority: id)`
end
```

Also have a look at [ActiveRlation update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

Example:

`Model.where(:foo => 'bar').where(:attr => 1).update_all("author = 'David'")`

Comment: > "what is the most efficient way to do a bulk update in Rails **(other than using transactions and update_all)**"

Comment: No, I'm not looking to set priority to id. Basically I am updating a lot of priorities to increment them by 1. I am looking at a raw SQL query that does a bulk update with best performance

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this.

```
UPDATE 
my_model 
SET priority = 
CASE 
  WHEN id = id1
    THEN p1
  WHEN id = id2
    THEN p2
  WHEN id = id3
    THEN p3
  WHEN id = id4
    THEN p4
  ELSE pX
END
```

Comment: No, I have over 20,000 ids I need to update, so I won't be able to use  `CASE`

Comment: then what exactly do u want to? There must be some pattern through which u want to update!

Comment: Hey, I figured out I could generate raw sql with CASE as you have mentioned. That worked. Thanks !

Comment: Pleasure is all mine!!